# Batch remove first occurrence of special characters in a .csv file

Tags: batch-file

I have a .csv file which has the following special characters in the second line of the first column of the file:

ï»¿Testing

[image]

I want to have a batch script which will remove these special characters and should look like this:

[image]

I have tried the following script but it clears everything from the file:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.csv) do @(
   findrepl "^ï»¿" "" < %%a > %%~na.csv
   del %%a
   ren %%~na.csv %%a
)
```

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe was "findrepl" is?

Comment: it finds the characters to be replaced.

Comment: Is it this: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697 batch command?  Just trying to understand the arguments it expects.

Comment: That is actually a script i found online. Unfortunately it is not working as expected. I thought someone else could guide me with something else.

Comment: These `ï»¿` characters are _CP1252_ appearance of the [**UTF-8** byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Import the CSV into an Excel-like app using UTF-8 encoding…

Comment: It appears to me as if your CSV files are the rersult of joining multiple files together below a header unique to them all. The issue is that each of those files were encoded as UTF-8 with BOM, and your joining process did not remove those byte order marks. My suggestion would be to revisit the process which joins those files, and modify it such that the BOM's are removed pre-processing or during the joining process. You will probably find that [tag:powershell] would be a better fit for that, not a [tag:batch-file].

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Compo, you should fix the process that creates the files. But it is possible to remove the problem characters from existing files.

Your code does not work for two reasons.

- `%%~na.csv` is the same as `%%a`, so you are immediately overwriting the content of the file with nothing when you redirect your output, and the entire script fails horribly. I like to append `.new` when temporarily creating a new version.
- [FINDREPL](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4697) is a batch script, so you need to use `call findrepl` when you include it in another batch script.

You should quote the file names, just in case there are spaces in the names.

It is probably more reliable to use a hex escape sequence to identify the problem characters.

Lastly, it is simpler and more efficient to use `move` instead of `del` and `ren`.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
   call findrepl "^\xEF\xBB\xBF" "" < "%%a" > "%%a.new"
   move /y "%%a.new" "%%a"
)
```

Another option is to use my [JREPL.BAT utility](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). It allows you to ignore temporary file issues.

From the command line:

```
for %F in (*.csv) do call jrepl "^\xEF\xBB\xBF" "" /f "%F" /o -
```

Of course you need to double the percents if you put the command in a batch script.